# Breaking while loop correctly under two conditions

Tags: python, while-loop

I am creating a python script where the user is prompted to guess what the secret number is and they have 6 tries to do so. I noticed that when I ran the program when the user guesses the number correctly, the last else statement in the while loop repeats twice and im not understanding why. I want the while loop to break when the user guesses number correctly and to also print a statement and also when the number of tries exceeds 6 and the user didn't guess the number correctly

```
def guessing_game(secret_number: int, user_guess: int):
  num_tries: int = 0
  user_name: str = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
  secret_number: int = randint(1, 20)
  user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))
  while num_tries != 6:
    if user_guess > secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too high. Try again: "))
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too low. Try again: "))
    else:
        print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
    num_tries += 1
if user_guess != secret_number and num_tries == 6:
    print(f"The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")
```

[image: This is when I saw the repeated statements]

Comment: You have  the answer in the question title. Use `break` to leave the loop if number is guessed.

Comment: Shouldn't you start your `num_tries` counter with `1`?

Comment: Usage of the `break` statement (which you reference in your question) is clearly documented in any tutorial on loops.  Please explain where you're stuck in applying that statement.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

To leave a loop in Python, you can use the `break` instruction. Here is how to use it in your code:

```py
def guessing_game(secret_number: int, user_guess: int):
  num_tries: int = 0
  user_name: str = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
  secret_number: int = randint(1, 20)
  user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))
  while num_tries != 6:
    if user_guess > secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too high. Try again: "))
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too low. Try again: "))
    else:
        print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
        break
    num_tries += 1
if user_guess != secret_number and num_tries == 6:
    print(f"The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")
```

However, you should remove the parameter `user_guess` and `secret_number` as you define it inside your function. Either you use them as parameter of the function or you define them into the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have reorganized it a bit. There is no need for a break, if you define the conditions right. In here we wait until the player guessed or the count is too high. Exactly as you wanted it. It ends under one of two conditions.

```py
import random
num_tries = 0
guessed = False

user_name: str = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
secret_number: int = random.randint(1, 20)

user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))
while num_tries < 6 and not guessed:
    if user_guess > secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too high. Try again: "))
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too low. Try again: "))
    else:
        guessed = True
        print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
    num_tries += 1

if not guessed:
    print(f"The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")
```